# When I share the embedded video link that I got from the Vimeo site on my Heroku app, it gives an error

Tags: django, heroku, video, html5-video, vimeo

[When I add the embedded video link, I am facing this error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJCdq.png)

I in the video I shared on Vimeo, I chose the option "Let only the allowed sites be able to embed". Then I added my own heroku site here. For ex:

1. my-site.herokuapp.com
2. herokuapp.com
3. heroku.com

Normally the video should start playing on my site. But it didn't work. Can you help?
How can I solve it?

Privacy : Hide from Vimeo
Embed : Specific domains

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try multi steps:

1 - Add this attribute to iframe tag `<iframe ...referrerpolicy="strict-origin"></iframe>`

2 - change the cookie policy, located under "Shields" > "Cookie Control", to "Allow all Cookies".

3 - Try different browsers to check if this is related to your browser and delete your cookies

Comment: @Jabrail I am very glad to hear that, You are welcome